# How to design a database for data which needs to be mapped at multiple levels?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

I have these following database entities:

1. Organization - Top level
2. Projects - Organization can have many projects.
3. Team Lead - Projects can have many team leads.

I have these following database tables already:

1. organizations

- orgnization_id
- (Other attributes)

2. organization_projects

   - organization_id (From organizations table)
   - project_id
   - (other attributes)
3. projects_team_leads

   - organization_project_id (From organization_projects table)
   - team_lead_id (which is id from the employee table)

Now, I would like to add one more entity here called contractors. The properties of contractors are as follows:

1. A team lead can have many contractors. There will be certain attributes associated in the mapping between a team lead and contractors such as manage_start_date
2. Some information also needs to be modelled between contractors and projects. For eg. rating of a contractor at "project" level.
3. Some information also needs to be modelled between contractors and organization as well. For eg. "contract_duration"

Also, note that only one team lead can manage a contractor inside a project.
Contractor also have global information such as name, dob etc. which reside in the employee table. However, this employee table is in another micro-service.

Current task is to add contractor to this service which has projects and organization and also add the necessary attributes at different levels (team lead level, project level and organization level).

I was thinking about having separate tables at each level. For eg.

1. organization_contractors

- organization_id
- contractor_id (From employee table in different micro-service)
- contract_duration

2. project_contractors

- organization_contractor_id (From organization_contractors table)
- organization_project_id (From organization_projects table)
- rating

3. team_lead_contractors

- project_team_lead_id (From project_team_leads table)
- contractor_project_id (From project_contractors table)
- manage_start_date

The only qualms I have about this is that in the team_lead_contractors table, the project can be inferred from both project_team_lead_id as well as contractor_project_id.

What are the pros and concern of this approach versus other approaches?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, ...

1. there are organizations and contractors.
2. An organization may have contracts with contractors A, B, C, and D.
3. One project in that organization may be related to some of these contaractors, say project P1 is related to A, B, and C, while project P2 is related to A and D.
4. Each project has project leads. Project P1 may have the leads PL1 and PL2.
5. Each project lead again may be related to all or only some of the project contractors. PL1 may be related to A and B, and PL2 to A and C.

If you want your DBMS to guarantee data consistency throughout all these entities, I suggest you use composite keys.

```
table organization
  organization_no
  ...

table contractor
  contractor_no
  ...

table organization_contractor
  organization_no
  contractor_no
  ...
  PK (organization_no, contractor_no)
  FK organization (organization_no)
  FK contractor (contractor_no)

table organization_project
  organization_no
  project_no
  ...
  PK (organization_no, project_no)
  FK organization (organization_no)

table organization_project_contractor
  organization_no
  project_no
  contractor_no
  ...
  PK (organization_no, project_no, contractor_no)
  FK organization_project (organization_no, project_no)
  FK organization_contractor (organization_no, contractor_no)

table organization_project_lead
  organization_no
  project_no
  lead_no
  ...
  PK (organization_no, project_no, lead_no)
  FK organization_project (organization_no, project_no)

table organization_project_lead_contractor
  organization_no
  project_no
  lead_no
  contractor_no
  ...
  PK (organization_no, project_no, lead_no, contractor_no)
  FK organization_project_lead (organization_no, project_no, lead_no)
  FK organization_project_contractor (organization_no, project_no, contractor_no)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! May I know what are the benefits of using composite keys? Isn't it redundant data which can be replaced by the key from the other table? For eg. organization_project_lead_contractor can have organization_project_lead_id.

Comment: No, composite keys are not redundant. Say, company 1 has a project 1 and company 2 also has a project 1. These are two different projects, so you need the company number plus the project number to access the project you are after. There is nothing redundant about that.

Comment: With single IDs you cannot guarantee consistency. That is kind of hard to explain. Well, a project lead contractor row would lead to a project lead and a contractor, The project lead again will lead to a project. And that project will be linked to contractors. But how to ensure that the project lead contractor is in the set of the project's contractors?

Comment: Ah! Okay! Got It. But, in our case, the project cannot be associated with another organization. All the projects inside that organization belong to that organization itself. Now, for team lead, they will always be under the same organization. However, they can work on multiple projects. They can be identified using organization_project_lead.id. In that case, which one is better? Having organization_project_lead.id inside organization_project_lead_contractor or having separate keys for organization_id, project_id and lead_id?

Comment: I don't know your business requirements. I assumed that projects belong to organizations and that their project leads would belong to the same organization. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If there is a project 1 inside company 1 as you said, the project 1 can never be associated with company 2 though. It will always be associated with company 1. Hence, if there are separate keys for organization_id, project_id inside organization_project_lead table, there should be a row for the same organization_id, project_id inside the organization_project table. Why can't we replace those two keys with this single organization_project.id?

Comment: With single surrogate keys the `organization_project_lead` table would only contain the organization_project.id. The problem is then the `organization_project_lead_contractor` table that must link to `organization_project_lead` and `organization_project_contractor` and it must somehow be guaranteed that these two tables link to the same project. With composite keys this is guaranteed, because the project ID is in both foreign keys. With single ID keys it is not.

Comment: Agreed! But, isn't that also a trade-off where I am not ensuring that the contractor also exists in the project_contractor table? With having separate keys, there is no way for me to ensure that a row also exists in the project_contractor table for that contractor. What are the pros and cons here?

Comment: With composite keys, the keys are a kind of chain going from table to table. You cannot have a row in the `organization_project_lead_contractor` table, that doesn't have a match in the `organization_project_lead` and the `organization_project_contractor` tables and hence in the tables `organization_project` and `organization_contractor`. That's what this is all about. There is no trade-off.

Comment: Okay, but, how can we ensure that the row exists in the parent table? i.e. I can any day enter a new row in the organization_project_lead_contractor table without a row being present in the organization_project_lead table and organization_project_contractor table. There is no foreign key check which will stop me from entering a row in the organization_project_lead_contractor table if there's no row present in the organization_project_lead table and organization_project_contractor table, right?

Comment: Of course there must be foreign key constraints. This is what I mean with FK in my answer. The table `organization_project_lead_contractor` has two foreign keys, one to `organization_project_lead (organization_no, project_no, lead_no)` and one to `organization_project_contractor (organization_no, project_no, contractor_no)`. This is what guarantees the consistency through all entities.

Comment: Just one question: is this approach of using composite keys better even if the hierarchy is 5 levels deep? i.e. we would be copying these 5 keys everywhere.

Comment: In my opinion this design is the more important the deeper the hierarchy. Don't worry about some bytes more in the tables.

Comment: And may I know why is it more important deeper the hierarchy?

Comment: The composite keys guarantee consistency in spite of a hierarchy, which single IDs do not. If table A has two child tables B and C and these have a child table D, then single keys cannot gurantee that you get to the same A row when going via D->B->A and D->C->A. The more hierarchy is in your database, the more of such constellations exist usually. So, with databases that have many levels of parent and child tables there can be more inconsistencies when using single table IDs.

Comment: Okay, I didn't quite get it. Which is the scenario where we would have problems getting from D to A?
I mean is it when we are inserting a new value into D or fetching a value from D or deleting a value from D?

Comment: Example: Empty database. You insert two rows into A. They get the IDs A1 and A2. You insert one row into B referencing A1 and it gets the ID B1 . You insert one row into C referencing A2 and it gets the ID C1. You insert a row into D referencing B1 and C1, which should not be possible, because your D now belongs to both A1 and A2. You have mistakenly inserted an invalid D row without knowing so. Later you may get problems and wonder whether this row was supposed to belong to B1 or to C1.

Comment: Now the same with composite IDs: You insert into A getting PKs A1 and A2. You insert into B getting PK A1/B1. You insert into C getting PK A2/C1. You insert into D, but that fails, because either you try A1/B1/C1, but then the DBMS will say that A1/C1 does not exist or you try A2/B1/C1, but then A2/B1 does not exist. You are not able to mistakenly insert an inconsistent D row.

Comment: Ah! Okay, sorry for asking for clarification. These are just the problems of having two keys which lead to the same parent. Got it. Thanks for your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to apply this concept of composite keys as foreign keys on another places in my application as well. I have a doubt. Should we use composite keys even if we do not have another branch from parent to child? Like above: if we did not have the concept of contractors, if we just had organization, project, team_lead should the organization_project_lead table still have (organization.id, project.id) as foreign key or organization_project.id as single key is fine in this case?